# Attempting to reverse an additive function I've learned

Tags: functions, inequality, arithmetic, inverse

So I discovered an easy way to add a succession of numbers together a while back, and I'm trying to reverse it for an RPG sheet in LibreOffice Calc.  The function probably has a name and I just don't know (or remember) it.  The function is basically an addition-based exponent, rather than a multiplication-based one.

So whereas with exponents,
you get $X^2 = X*X$.

With this function,
$\frac {X*(X+1)}{2} = Y$ where $Y = 1+2+3+...+X$
For example, if $X = 12, \frac {12*13}{2} = 78 = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12$

That said, I want to do the inverse of my "discovery," where $Y >$ (insert wizardry here) $> X$, using the $Y$ and $X$ of the above function.

1. Does anyone know a name for my "discovered" function?
2. Does anyone know a way to inverse that function?

Comment: Please use MathJax. After 8 months in the site, you've probably seen it used a time or two. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), in case you haven't.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh, hadn't seen that before.  I'll try that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally true that $\sum_{i= 1}^n i= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

To invert that, if $y= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ then $n(n+1)= n^2+ n= 2y$ so that $n^2+ n- 2y= 0$.

By the quadratic equation, $n= \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+ 8y}}{2}$.

Since $n$ must be positive, $n= \frac{-1+ \sqrt{1+ 8y}}{2}$.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it; it went over my head at first.  Let me make sure I can do this in Calc.

Comment: Thank you!  It took me a moment, I appear to be rustier on my algebra than I thought.